# how to manually adjust view switching speed with swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, catransition

I am using CATransition for the next view to present over another from right. Now i want to control this view transition using swipe gesture so that user can swipe from left to right and next view present on screen with the thumb speed and position . So that user can feel the realness

my transition code is

```
 let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : drawer = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("drawerID") as! drawer



    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    let timeFunc : CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.duration = 0.50
    transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight    //kCATransitionFromLeft
    self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

Comment: I remember reading this tutorial, maybe it will be of use for you: http://mathewsanders.com/interactive-transitions-in-swift

Comment: Yeah thanks ....I need the same implementation...